# Delphi service app crashes at a random time

Tags: delphi, service, crash, ado, indy

I have a Delphi Service app. Indy TCP server and many clients (up to 50), ADO connection to Firebird and simply network exchange. App randomly crashes (may be workin 7 days, may be 1 hour) with next event (for example):

> Имя сбойного приложения: rollcontrol.exe, версия: 1.1.20.2, метка времени: 0x60acd5f2
> Имя сбойного модуля: ntdll.dll, версия: 6.3.9600.19678, метка времени: 0x5e82c0f7
> Код исключения: 0xc0000005
> Смещение ошибки: 0x00058def
> Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x4178

or:

> Имя сбойного приложения: rollcontrol.exe, версия: 1.1.1.9, метка времени: 0x607b239c
> Имя сбойного модуля: msvcrt.dll, версия: 7.0.9600.16384, метка времени: 0x52158ff5
> Код исключения: 0xc0000005
> Смещение ошибки: 0x00009e80

All jobs in app makes in anonimius threads or in tcp/ip connections threads. All code in each thread executed in try except statments. There no memory leaks or growing threads count. The main code of service thread very simple:

```
procedure TRollControl_Svc.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin

  while not Terminated do
  try
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);
    ServiceThread.Sleep(100);
  except
    on e : exception do LogException('ServiceExecute', E);
  end;

end;
```

How I can handled this exception and prevent app crash? How it possible to crash service thread with two simple lines of code?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** Example of connections to DB:

```
function TRollControl_Svc.GetNodeIdByIP(ip: string): integer;
Var
    SQLConnection : TADOConnection;
    SQLQuery : TADOQuery;
    Thread : TThread;
    fResult : integer;
begin

    fResult := 0;

    try
      Thread := nil;
      Thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin

        try

          SQLConnection := nil;
          SQLQuery := nil;

          CoInitialize(nil);

          SQLConnection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
          SQLConnection.ConnectionString := 'Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=' + Psw + ';Persist Security Info=True;User ID=' + Usr + ';Data Source=' + Srv ;
          SQLConnection.LoginPrompt := false;

          SQLQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
          SQLQuery.Connection := SQLConnection;
          SQLQuery.LockType := ltReadOnly;

          try SQLConnection.Open; except SQLConnection.Open; end;
          SQLConnection.BeginTrans;

          SQLQuery.Close;
          SQLQuery.SQL.Text := 'select nodes.* from nodes where nodes.ip = :ip';
          SQLQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('ip').Value := ip;
          try SQLQuery.Open; except SQLQuery.Open; end;

          if SQLQuery.IsEmpty then exit;

          fResult := SQLQuery.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;

          if SQLConnection.InTransaction then
            SQLConnection.CommitTrans;

        finally

          TryFree(SQLQuery);
          TryFree(SQLConnection);

          CoUninitialize;
        end;

      end
      );
      Thread.FreeOnTerminate := false;
      Thread.Start;
      Thread.WaitFor;
    finally
      TryFree(Thread);
    end;

    result := fResult;

end;
```

Comment: the code you have shown here is fine, in fact you can omit that piece of code, it is better not to implement OnServiceexecute as it will do exactly the same thing.  0xc0000005 is an external exception, most likely in the ADO COM layer but we cannot see that code here...

Comment: All connections to ADO executed in separated threads like TThread.CreateAnonymousThread from TIDTCPServerExecute procedure. All code in try/except statments. I did not understand why main thread crashes and how catch exeception before prcess terminated

Comment: Without a [mcve] that demonstrates the errors in action, there is no way for anyone to diagnose this for you. You are just going to have to debug your service to catch the errors when they happen. In the simply description you have mentioned, there is a lot that can go wrong

Comment: I don't see the added value of those anonymous threads, each TCP connection will already happen in it's own thread context, I guess you are corrupting memory somewhere causing a general crash. Add some logging if you are unable to debug the service.

Answer (score 1):

Error Handling

This isn't an answer as to what is causing your problem, but I thought it probably wouldn't be clear in a comment.

In languages that support structured exception handling the language gives the programmer an opportunity to fail gracefully when things don't work.  That's not how you are using it.  From your example anonymous thread you have:

```pascal
  try SQLConnection.Open; except SQLConnection.Open; end;
```

So you are told that the connection can't be made and instead of responding to that situation you go ahead and attempt to connect again.  There are lots of reasons why a connection may not work, some of those are transient so the attempt may work a little later but if you simply try doing it again without any pause it seems reasonable to expect it to fail again.

It's obviously important to catch errors, but you have to have appropriate failure paths.

I have no way of knowing if this is related to what's actually going wrong.

Comment: I have many "short" connections to database, and and very often query are not opened by error inside ADO. Retry solves these problems in 99.9% times, I think no reason to recreate connection and new thread in this case. Now I set System.NeverSleepOnMMThreadContention := false and move TADOConnection.Create(nil) outside try/finally block, waiting results...

Comment: @НиколайНевзоров what Rob means, when using the `except` clause, try to catch the specific exception (ex. The Ado specifc ones) and raise others, which are not ADO related so you know for sure that was the actual problem you’re trying to resolve. This way your sure you’re not hitting the 0.1% of the other failures in this case…

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason. The problem was in the ADO source codes (Data.Win.ADODB.pas):

```
  procedure RefreshFromOleDB;
  var
    I: Integer;
    ParamCount: ULONG_PTR;
    ParamInfo: PDBParamInfoArray;
    NamesBuffer: POleStr;
    Name: WideString;
    Parameter: _Parameter;
    Direction: ParameterDirectionEnum;
    OLEDBCommand: ICommand;
    OLEDBParameters: ICommandWithParameters;
    CommandPrepare: ICommandPrepare;
  begin
    OLEDBCommand := (Command.CommandObject as ADOCommandConstruction).OLEDBCommand as ICommand;
    OLEDBCommand.QueryInterface(ICommandWithParameters, OLEDBParameters);
    OLEDBParameters.SetParameterInfo(0, nil, nil); // ----- Error here
    if Assigned(OLEDBParameters) then
    begin
      ParamInfo := nil;
      NamesBuffer := nil;
      try
        OLEDBCommand.QueryInterface(ICommandPrepare, CommandPrepare);
        if Assigned(CommandPrepare) then CommandPrepare.Prepare(0);
        if OLEDBParameters.GetParameterInfo(ParamCount, PDBPARAMINFO(ParamInfo), @NamesBuffer) = S_OK then
          for I := 0 to ParamCount - 1 do//
          begin
            { When no default name, fabricate one like ADO does }
            if ParamInfo[I].pwszName = nil then
              Name := 'Param' + IntToStr(I+1) else { Do not localize }
              Name := ParamInfo[I].pwszName;
            { ADO maps DBTYPE_BYTES to adVarBinary }
            if ParamInfo[I].wType = DBTYPE_BYTES then ParamInfo[I].wType := adVarBinary;
            { ADO maps DBTYPE_STR to adVarChar }
            if ParamInfo[I].wType = DBTYPE_STR then ParamInfo[I].wType := adVarChar;
            { ADO maps DBTYPE_WSTR to adVarWChar }
            if ParamInfo[I].wType = DBTYPE_WSTR then ParamInfo[I].wType := adVarWChar;
            Direction := ParamInfo[I].dwFlags and $F;
            { Verify that the Direction is initialized }
            if Direction = adParamUnknown then Direction := adParamInput;
            Parameter := Command.CommandObject.CreateParameter(Name, ParamInfo[I].wType, Direction, ParamInfo[I].ulParamSize, EmptyParam);
            Parameter.Precision := ParamInfo[I].bPrecision;
            Parameter.NumericScale := ParamInfo[I].bScale;
            //if ParamInfo[I].dwFlags and $FFFFFFF0 <= adParamSigned + adParamNullable + adParamLong then
            Parameter.Attributes := ParamInfo[I].dwFlags and $FFFFFFF0; { Mask out Input/Output flags }
            AddParameter.FParameter := Parameter;
          end;
      finally
        if Assigned(CommandPrepare) then CommandPrepare.Unprepare;
        if (ParamInfo <> nil) then GlobalMalloc.Free(ParamInfo);
        if (NamesBuffer <> nil) then GlobalMalloc.Free(NamesBuffer);
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Line

```
OLEDBParameters.SetParameterInfo(0, nil, nil)
```

executed before

```
if Assigned(OLEDBParameters)
```

I moved this line after checking on nil and all working fine

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using? I checked in current Delphi version (10.4.2) and the offending line you found is at the correct place.

Comment: I have Delphi XE3 :(

Comment: Ouch, very old version, released in 2012. You should probably upgrade to the most recent version (10.4.2) to get all bug fixes since XE3. It has a cost but you'll spent much more money fighting with such errors.

Comment: glad you found the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to isolate the problem. Errors occur periodically when working with ADO. If I try to use TADOQuery objects again, the application more susceptible to crashes. What I've done:

1. System.NeverSleepOnMMThreadContention: = false;
   Significantly reduces errors when working with ADO
2. All uses of TADOQuery are single use.

For example it was:

```
            for ii := 0 to SettingsXML.Root.NamedItem['sql_clear_base'].NamedItem['XML'].Count - 1 do
            begin

                try
                  SQLQuery.Close;
                  SQLQuery.SQL.Text := SettingsXML.Root.NamedItem['sql_clear_base'].NamedItem['XML'][ii].AsString;
                  SQLQuery.ExecSQL;
                except
                  on e : exception do LogException('ClearBase', '', E);
                end;

            end;
```

Became:

```
            for ii := 0 to SettingsXML.Root.NamedItem['sql_clear_base'].NamedItem['XML'].Count - 1 do
            begin

              SQLQuery := nil;
              try
                SQLQuery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
                SQLQuery.Connection := SQLConnection;
                try
                  SQLQuery.Close;
                  SQLQuery.SQL.Text := SettingsXML.Root.NamedItem['sql_clear_base'].NamedItem['XML'][ii].AsString;
                  SQLQuery.ExecSQL;
                except
                  on e : exception do LogException('ClearBase', '', E);
                end;
              finally
                TryFree(SQLQuery);
              end;

            end;
```

3. I make self-control:

- main procces started as windows service (process A)
- process A starts a copy of itself as B
- one per minutes A check if B alive and restart if not
- one per minutes B check if A alive and restart if not
- check - simple TCP packet and answer

For example:

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
procedure
var tcpClient : TidTCPClient;
begin

  tcpClient := nil;
  LastKeepAlive := Date + Time;

  while ServerMode do
  begin

    try
      if not Assigned(tcpClient) then
      begin
        tcpClient := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
        tcpClient.Host := '127.0.0.1';
        tcpClient.Port := RollControl_Svc.TCPServer.Bindings[0].Port;
        tcpClient.Connect;
        tcpClient.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 1000;
      end;
      tcpClient.IOHandler.Write(START_PACKET + #0 + END_PACKET);
      tcpClient.IOHandler.ReadString(3);
      LastKeepAlive := Date + Time;
    except
      TryFree(tcpClient);
    end;

    sleep(15 * 1000);
  end;

end).Start;

TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
procedure
Var Res: TRequestResult;
begin

  while ServerMode do
  begin
    if Date + Time - LastKeepAlive > OneMinute then
    begin
      Res.Clear('', '');
      Res.Nodes_ID := -1;
      Res.Data_In := 'KeepAlive';
      Res.Data_Out := 'Exception: ExitProcess(1)';
      try
        Log(Res, true);
      finally
        ExitProcess(1);
      end;
    end;

    sleep(1000);
  end;

end).Start;
```

P.S. Local tests never crashed applications. The program simply proceed a million requests (connect, request, disconnect), there are no memory leaks or failures. On several clients servers are crashed. In the future I want to port to Lazarus to use ODBC directly insteed ADO