# Delphi ADO.Command named parameters

Tags: delphi, ado

I trying simple code on Delphi:

```
  Connection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
  Connection.ConnectionString := 'dsn=rollcontrol_im';
  Connection.Open;

  Command := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
  Command.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM log where log.id = :id';
  Command.ActiveConnection := Connection;
  Command.Parameters.Append( Command.CreateParameter('id', adInteger, adParamInput, 4 {size}, 5 {value}) );

  RecordSet := Command.Execute();
```

And I got an error:

> [ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]Dynamic SQL Error
> SQL error code = -206
> Column unknown
> ID
> At line 1, column 35.

If I change param name to ? its working fine:

```
  Connection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
  Connection.ConnectionString := 'dsn=rollcontrol_im';
  Connection.Open;

  Command := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
  Command.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM log where log.id = ?';
  Command.ActiveConnection := Connection;
  Command.Parameters.Append( Command.CreateParameter('?', adInteger, adParamInput, 4 {size}, 5 {value}) );

  RecordSet := Command.Execute();
```

How I can use named parameters with OLE ADO.Commanad ? Whats wrong ?

Tnx

Comment: Why use `CreateOleObject` instead of the Delphi ADO components that comes with Delphi? I mean `TADOConnection`, `TADOQuery` and `TADOCommand` among others in the dbGO component palette tab.

Comment: I have a randomly app crash on several clients serververs with ADO components. Now trying to working directly

Comment: @НиколайНевзоров: I use the TADO components in all my apps, I can assure you, they work fine. Probably an error in your application is causing this issue. Are you using multithreading?

Comment: @НиколайНевзоров I have many applications using ADO component without ever a single problem. If you own application crash, you'd better find what is the cause because you'll probably just reproduce that error. I suggest you create a new question describing the crash you experience and ask for help.

Comment: I have delphi XE3. Now I corrected one error in Data.Win.AdoDB.pas (calling  OLEDBParameters.SetParameterInfo(0, nil, nil) in RefreshFromOleDB before checking Assigning(OLEDBParameters). Qty of errors (acces violation) is redused, but not clear yet. P.S. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693135/delphi-service-app-crashes-at-a-random-time/67700087

Comment: I suggest you use [madExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) tool to find buffer overflow or underflow and access of object after destruction and similar problems. And also of course memory leaks and resource leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:ParamName` is Delphi's placeholder for named parameters in its SQL wrapper components, like `TADOQuery`. It is not ADO's native syntax, `?` is the correct placeholder for parameters when working with ADO's OLE API directly.